# Pandas to replace value using map function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the pandas Dataframe like that( data.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9fjM.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhDov.png)I want to replace single value '218.188.2.4' in the part [0, '218.188.2.4'] using a dict(dat1)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVaf1.png).

I am thinking whether you have more efficient way or function to do that.
Hope to get your response for that.

I got the Nan finally after I used the map function. I know it can only replace value with single value. I know trying to write a function to replace that is possible. While it is a little bit complex.

with map function: 
fd_id['parameter value vector'].map(token_encode_dict)

return NaN at the corresponding position

Comment: You need to change the formatting of your question in order to be readable. Also, your image is not included properly. No one is going to spend time looking at this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if i correctly understand your question, but you can map the dict values across the columns as follows..

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
     A    B    C    D
0   no   no   no  yes
1  yes  yes  yes   no
2  yes   no  yes   no
3   no  yes   no  yes
```

### Result:

```
>>> for col in 'ABCD':
     df[col] = df[col].map({'yes':True, 'no':False})

>>> df
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False   True
1   True   True   True  False
2   True  False   True  False
3  False   True  False   True
```

Comment: You are right to solve the single value using map function. When it is like [no, yes, no], it will return NaN. So trying to split it into multiple columns and then use map function will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Map function can only be used to process single value(not a list).
You can split the list into different columns and use map to replace values. Then you can integrate all the columns together to achieve replacement.

Comment: Hi @Newt. see the posted answer if that's something can be helpful.

Comment: A    B    C    D
0   no   no   no  yes
1  yes  yes  yes   [no,'1','2']
2  yes   no  yes   no
3   no  yes   no  yes          In fact, I need to modify the 'no' is a list. Map function can not do that.